# Customise slack message with if block in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, slack

I have a requirement to send out a slack message via jenkins post build step based on certain condition. I have put the below code snippet under "Custom Message" of Slack Notification of my jenkins build. Below prints the entire content of get_schedule_response.txt.

`Here's the result for the schedule execution --------> ${FILE,path="$WORKSPACE/get_schedule_response.txt"}`

I want to send out this slack notification only if the get_schedule_response.txt file content contains text SUCCESS in it. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

by using grep command u can find out the word SUCESSS in the file get_schedule_response.txt file

```
if [(grep -o "SUCCESS" "$WORKSPACE/get_schedule_response.txt"}) = "SUCCESS"];
then
#include your slack notification for success
else
#include your slack notification for success

# -o : Print only the matched parts of a matching line,
```

to refer all options for grep command follow this link

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/grep-command-in-unixlinux/

Comment: Sorry for delay. I was out sick. This lines of code in jenkins prints everything, which are part of if condition as well. It does not consider the if braced code as condition. Slack msg itself looks, something like:

if [(grep -o "SUCCESS" "$WORKSPACE/get_schedule_response.txt"}) = "SUCCESS"];
.
.
else
.
.